# select2 › select2 tag creation on blur not working in 4.0.0 version

Tags: jquery-select2, blur

When you type a new value and click outside the select2 without entering space or comma, the text disappears... which is kind of confusing for front-end users. It should auto create as a tag on blur if its a new value.

```
$("#cccc, #bccc").select2({
    tags: true,    
    multiple: true,
    selectOnClose: true,
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
});
```

When I am adding selectOnClose: true, (in 3.3 version it was selectOnBlur: true) It seems that there is a cyclic error occurs in last 4.0.0 version

Thanks!

Comment: [This is a known bug in Select2 4.0.0.](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3169)

Answer (score 3):

In select2 4.0.0, there was an infinite loop when `selectOnClose` and `closeOnSelect` (true by default) were both set to true. See Kevin's comment. This issue has been [resolved in select2 4.0.1](https://github.com/select2/select2/releases/tag/4.0.1) (see bug fixes).